# Alinhar Cards CSS Bootstrap

Tags: css

Olá, gostaria de alinhar os cards do centro da minha página
Print:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```css
*{
    font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
}

.logo{
    max-width: 27%;
}

.content-wrapper {
    max-width: 1250px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 50px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    position: relative;
    margin: -40px auto 0;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 10;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

footer{
    background: #131313;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

footer p {
    color: #bdbdbd;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.card img {
    margin-top: 15px;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    max-width: 130px;
}

.card {
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 400px;
    background: #fff;

}

.mid {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    
}

.presentation {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60vh;
    background: url(../images/bg-1.jpg) top center;
}



.widget {
    background: white;
    margin: 25px 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta name="google" value="notranslate">
    <meta name="language" content="pt-br" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="pt-br" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow,noodp,noydir">
    <meta name="revisit-after" content="1 week">
    <base href="/">
    <link rel="canonical" href="http://localhost/" />

    <title>Atlas Plugins - Início</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Atlas Plugins de Minecraft - Home">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Minecraft, Plugins de Minecraft, Plugins, Plugin, Servidor de Minecraft, Servidor, Plugins para servidor de minecraft, plugins para minecraft, pl para servidores de minecraft, pl minecraft, pl de factions, pl da redesky">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#79C9F9">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://localhost/app/content/assets/images/A.png">

    <meta property="og:title" content="Atlas Plugins" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://localhost/app/content/assets/images/logo.png" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
    <meta property="og:locale" content="pt_BR" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Atlas Plugins" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Atlas Plugins de Minecraft - Home" />

    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
    <meta name="twitter:site" content="Atlas Plugins" />
    <meta name="twitter:title" content="Atlas Plugins - Início" />
    <meta name="twitter:description" content="Atlas Plugins de Minecraft - Home" />
    <meta name="twitter:image" content="http://localhost/app/content/assets/images/logo.png" />

    <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,300,700|Ubuntu:300,400,500,700&subset=Latin" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="/app/content/assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/app/content/assets/css/bootstrap/bootstrap-reboot.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/app/content/assets/css/normalize/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="/app/content/assets/css/waves/waves.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/app/content/assets/css/sweetalert/sweetalert.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="/app/content/assets/css/animate/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/app/content/assets/css/atlas.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4a0796fb5d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar menu navbar-expand-md">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="/" class="navbar-brand"><img src="/app/content/assets/images/A.png" class="logo" alt="Atlas Plugins - Logo"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler waves waves-effect waves-light" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu"> <span class="ion-navicon"></span> </button>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse justify-content-stretch" id="menu">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="/"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Início</a> </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="javascript:void(0)" id="pluginsDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"> <i class="fas fa-plug"></i> Plugins </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="pluginsDropdown"> <a class="dropdown-item" href="/loja">Pagos</a> <a class="dropdown-item" href="/loja/free">Gratuitos</a> </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"> </li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="/contato"><i class="fas fa-id-badge"></i> Contato</a> </li>
                <li class="nav-item private"> <a class="nav-link waves waves-effect waves-light" href="/client/login"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Área do Cliente</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<header class="presentation">
    <div class="mid">
    <div class="row">
        
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card wow  zoomIn animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: zoomIn;"> <img src="/app/content/assets/images/upgrade.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Icone Indisponível">
            <br>
            <h4 class="text-center">Atualizações</h4>
            <p class="text-center">Todos os plugins recebem updates sempre que possível</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card wow  zoomIn animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: zoomIn;"> <img src="/app/content/assets/images/fast.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Icone Indisponível">
            <br>
            <h4 class="text-center">Agilidade</h4>
            <p class="text-center">Suporte, desenvolvimento e entrega rápida e no prazo estipulado.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card wow  zoomIn animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: zoomIn;"> <img src="/app/content/assets/images/security.png" class="img-fluid" alt="Icone Indisponível">
            <br>
            <h4 class="text-center">Segurança</h4>
            <p class="text-center">Compra segura e plugins totalmente livre de malicia desenvolvidos em ambiente seguro.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="content-wrapper">
<div class="blank">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2"> <img src="https://minotar.net/avatar/gabriel_blink" class="img-fluid" alt="TintaDev - Ideia"> </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <h3>Sobre Mim</h3>
            <p class="text-justify"> Olá, seja muito bem vindo ao Atlas Plugins!
                <br> Meu nome é Gabriel e sou desenvolvedor java desde 2014, 
                <br> Atualmente desenvolvo para muitos servidores de portes variados, e estou a disposição para melhorar seu servidor também.
                <br> Está esperando o que para conhecer mais sobre meu trabalho? Baixe meus <a href="/loja/free" target="_blank">plugins gratuitos</a> e aprove a qualidade.
                <br> Caso queira projetos para melhorar seu servidor ainda mais, veja alguns <a href="/loja" target="_blank">recursos pagos</a> e caso não encontre o que precisa entre em <a href="/contato" target="_blank">contato</a> e faça uma encomenda exclusiva como deseja. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<footer>
   <div class="copyright">
      <p><i class="far fa-copyright"></i> Copyright Atlas Plugins 2020 - Todos os direitos reservados.</p>
   </div>
</footer>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="/app/content/assets/js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/leonardosnt/mc-player-counter/1.0.0/dist/mc-player-counter.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/clipboard.js/1.5.13/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<script src="/app/content/assets/js/popper/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="/app/content/assets/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/app/content/assets/js/waves/waves.min.js"></script>
<script src="/app/content/assets/js/wow/wow.min.js"></script>
<script src="/app/content/assets/js/sweetalert/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<script async src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Coloque a classe `.justify-content-center` na `div.row` onde estão os cards para que eles fiquem alinhados ao centro. A `div.row` já é flexbox e essa classe, nativa no Bootstrap 4, alinha os elementos filhos ao centro horizontalmente.

Retire o `width: 400px;` da classe `.cards` para que eles sejam responsivos. Eles já estão dentro de uma coluna responsiva, então não precisa definir uma largura fixa para eles senão um ficará por cima do outro se reduzir a largura da tela até certo ponto antes do breakpoint do `.col-md-3`.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o display flex na div que você usa como container para seus card e utilize
"justify-content: space-around;". Segue exemplo.

Eu recomendo que você dê uma olhada em display flex e grid.

Este código é css puro, coloquei-o pois você não utilizou a tag do twitter bootstrap.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

#container > div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 140px;
  border-radius: 10%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Teste de Página</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>  
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Estou utilizando o container mas coloquei um ```margin-top: 100px;``` e de acordo com a resolução do monitor fica diferente, como posso ajustar isso para um padrão em todos os monitores?, segue exemplos em imagens de 2 prints de monitores diferentes:

[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][1]][1]


[![inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSM52.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sq1MV.png

Comment: Não sei um jeito de te ajudar com isso, mas acho que você deveria fazer um novo post, pois acho que esta pergunta sobre padrão em resoluções diferentes já sai do contexto de alinhamento de cards.

Answer (score 0):

Estou utilizando o container mas coloquei um `margin-top: 100px;` e de acordo com a resolução do monitor fica diferente, como posso ajustar isso para um padrão em todos os monitores?, segue exemplos em imagens de 2 prints de monitores diferentes:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]